# SQL counting rows with matching value

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table with the following values:

name_table

```
ID  Name  
1   Bob  
2   James  
3   Bob  
4   Joe
```

I am trying to do a search where it will give me the list names and how many times the name was found. What I am looking for is a result like this:

```
Bob 2  James 1  Joe 1
```

The code:

```
(connection info)  
$query = "SELECT name, count(*) FROM name_table GROUP BY name;  
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (Could not execute query"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) 
echo ("$row['name']");
```

It is showing me the names but not the count.

Comment: Why are you using `msql_error()` with `myqli_query()` ?

Comment: Gordon, forgive it's a typo, its mysqli_error I use it in hopes of getting something to give me an idea of what is not working, even if it's just a line number to give me a place to look. I do this as a hobby. :)

Comment: You are missing a closing " from the 1st line of your code (see the syntax highlighting).

Comment: And you are not fetching the results. See duplicate question.

Comment: Shadow, I did search. Perhaps I did not recognize it, could I get a link perhaps?

Comment: Shadow, forgive, I found the link above, thank you.

Comment: You do not echo the count, so don't know what you expect...

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT name, count(name) FROM name_table GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: Osama, thank you, I closed the statement but still no joy.